# Heavy await/async when the Visual Studio Debugger is attached is slow?

Tags: visual-studio, async-await, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I have a clean install of Visual Studio 2022 (community edition). I was trying to work out why my importer which utilises EF Core was so slow, but then noticed it's not actually the code itself that's slow, it's the VS debugger causing it to slow down.

I made a minimal code test to reproduce the issue (please don't critique/alter the code, this is purely a barebones example to highlight the issue). The real-world code is nothing like this, but it encounters the same issue.

```cs
    public class TestItem
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int TestNum { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestItem> TestItems { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=efdebugtest;Username=postgres;Password=...");

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestItem>().HasIndex(r => r.TestNum);
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            void L(string str) => Console.WriteLine(str);

            using var ctx = new AppDbContext();
            await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
            await ctx.Database.MigrateAsync();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100_000).Select(i => new TestItem()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                TestNum = i,
            });
            L($"Items Generated: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");

            sw.Restart();
            await ctx.AddRangeAsync(items);
            L($"Items Added: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");

            sw.Restart();
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            L($"Items Saved: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");

            ConcurrentBag<int> foundItems = new();
            var testChunks = Enumerable.Range(0, 200_000).OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(20_000).Chunk(2500);
            await Parallel.ForEachAsync(testChunks, async (chunk, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                using var threadCtx = new AppDbContext();
                var threadSw = new Stopwatch();
                threadSw.Start();
                foreach (var num in chunk)
                {
                    var dbEntry = await threadCtx.TestItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ti => ti.TestNum == num);
                    if (dbEntry != null)
                    {
                        foundItems.Add(dbEntry.TestNum);
                    }
                }
                L($"Thread finished search: {threadSw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");
            });
        }
    }
```

If I run this in debug mode with the debugger attached it's very slow, each 'search' thread takes 17-18s.

```
Items Generated: 0.0003297s
Items Added: 0.6718225s
Items Saved: 4.2752014s
Thread finished search: 17.2668618s
Thread finished search: 17.2820979s
...
Thread finished search: 17.4786316s
Thread finished search: 17.4891402s
```

If I run it in debug mode **without** the debugger attached it's fast, each 'search' thread takes less than 1 second:

```
Items Generated: 0.0002435s
Items Added: 0.6201017s
Items Saved: 4.025146s
Thread finished search: 0.8171215s
Thread finished search: 0.8336687s
...
Thread finished search: 0.8410876s
Thread finished search: 0.8419168s
```

If I change the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to the regular `FirstOrDefault`:

```cs
var dbEntry = threadCtx.TestItems.FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.TestNum == num);
```

It's fast (< 1 second per search thread) both with and without the debugger attached.

Has anyone encountered this or have any idea what VS debugger setting might be causing it? Ideally I don't want to have to change to using the non-async FirstOrDefault purely to keep the debugger functioning correctly because when the debugger isn't attached it works fine.

I tried disabling the diagnostic tools (options -> debugging -> general -> enable diagnostic tools while debugging) but that made no difference.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply, I'm not quite sure what you mean? Even if I disable all the diagnostics tools, close all the debug windows and disable my any security software (MSE) it still happens.

Comment: This is normal and working as expected. Running in Debug Mode with the debugger attached is *always* going to be slow/unusable for realtime-speed applications.

Comment: @Casey I understand debugger attached will always be slower, but is it really to be expected that a basic async/await call is 20x slower while debugging and there's no setting that can speed it up?

Comment: OK it looks to be related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38736 because if I use the patched runtime that removes `NotifyOfCrossThreadDependencySlow` it runs the same speed as with/without the debugger attached. Pretty wild that issue has been open for 4 years and there's not even a temporary fix of allowing the user to force it off without patching the framework (although ideally they'd actually fix it and only fire when it should fire, i.e. func evals on break)